# Can we handle all signals in single proc in Tcl

Tags: signals, tcl, expect

I am working on tcl code. I need to handle all possible signals in single function in tcl.
Is there any easy way in doing that.

Eg:

```
signal trap SIGINT mySIGFunc;  # This Handles signal only from SIGINT
```

Like this I want to register all signals to this function alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In expect, you can do this (because the signal to trap is actually a *list* of signal identifiers, which can be numeric or named):

```
# Make a signal ID list in $sigs
set sigs {}
for {set i 1} {$i <= 31} {incr i} {lappend sigs $i}

# Set the trap callback for each of the signals
trap mySIGFunc $sigs
```

OK, some of those signals aren't actually trappable (e.g., SIGKILL=9, SIGSTOP=17) but it won't hurt to set a trap on them. You might in fact want to use an explicit list so that you don't trap anything you don't expect. For example, it's almost certainly a mistake to trap any of the signals that cause a core dump to be created by default; those tend to be thrown when recovery is already unlikely to be possible.